# Android Float To Int

Tags: android, floating-point, integer

Why is this so hard to find out?

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
```

I need to convert `float event.getY()` to an int.

Is this possible?

`event.getY().intValue()` will not work at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Uhhh, yeah, how about:

```
int y = (int)event.getY();
```

You see `getY()` only returns a float for devices that have a sub-pixel accuracy.

Comment: It always returns a float.  Maybe you mean the float represents an integer?

Comment: Correct.  On devices that don't have sub-pixel accuracy the float is always something like 235.0.  You can just cast to an int to get the pixel value.

Answer (score 2):

Using

`Math.round(yourFloat);`

is better than

`(int)yourFloat;`

It is all about precision. If you use `(int)` you'll just get numbers after the point removed. If you use `Math`, you'll get a rounded number. It doesn't seems like a big deal.For example, if you try to round something like 3.1, both methods would produce the same result - 3.

But take 3.9 or 3.8. It's practically 4, yet

`(int)3.9 = 3`

whereas

`Math.round(3.9) = 4`

Comment: What about (int)(some_float + 0.5) ?

Comment: Result depends on value of `some_float`. If it has 1 decimal after point, like x.5 to x.9, then result will be x + 1 `(x.5 + 0.5 = x+1)`, if x.0 to x.04 - just x `(x.4 + 0.5 = x.9)`. But still, this won't work as Math.round. 1.46 + 0.5 = 1.96. (int)1.96 = 1. In that case, to get precise result, you would need to have some_float + 0.5555555555...infinity

Comment: I don't see the problem. I would expect 1.46 to be rounded to 1 as it is less than 1.5.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how rounding works. Rounding is not recursive. If you want to round to the nearest increment, then all that is done is a comparison with the half-way point. If the input is larger, round up. If it is smaller, round down. If it is equal, then generally accepted practice is to round up. 1.46 is closer to 1 than 2, so if you are rounding to the closest integer, then you will round it to 1.

Comment: Yeah, Math.round(1.46) returns 1. See ideone.com/Lj43Dh .

Comment: Couldn't be helped then.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it:

```
int val = (int)event.getY();
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Answer (score 0):

Math.round() will round the float to the nearest integer.